# NET Core 5 How to override an action on a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-5.0, asp.net-routing

Let's imagine I have a "*platform*" with some basic features. It has its own set of controllers with actions delivered as a class library. For example, let's name it as `CartController` with `Order` action, as a result, API URL will be `Cart/Order`.

For some reason, I want to extend logic in Order process, I added `MyCartController` with `Order` action in my project where I reference the *platform*. Now I need to set up the app to use my custom action instead of the original one.

In ASP MVC 5 (based on .NET Framework) I can do it as follows

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        var route = new Route("Cart/Order", new RouteValueDictionary(new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "action", nameof(MyCartController.Order) },
            { "controller", nameof(MyCartController).Replace("Controller", "") }
        }), new MvcRouteHandler());

        routes.Insert(RouteTable.Routes.Count - 2, route);
    }
}
```

and then call it from Startup as

```
public override void Configuration(IAppBuilder builder)
{
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

and it worked well.

But after migration to .Net Core 5, it stopped working.
In Startup, I added

```
public virtual void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => 
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute("MyCartOrder", "Cart/Order", new { controller = nameof(MyCartController).Replace("Controller", ""), action = nameof(MyCartController.Order) });
        });
}
```

with no luck. It looks like they broke something helpful here https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Routing/ControllerActionEndpointDataSource.cs#L100

I tried to decorate my controller with `Route("Cart")` attribute and `HttpPost("Order")` with `AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints` exception.

I have no idea of how to override it then.

So my question is: **How to override the route to use my action on my controller in .Net Core 5?** What is the equivalent of routes.Add from .Net 4.8 which works for URL matching but not only for links generation?

Any thoughts and ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: I see only config code. I don't think that you need this code at all. Can you show the controllers pls? I mean controller action headers and how they are related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mark the needed action in the "override" controller with `Http{Method}Attribute` and set [`Order`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.routing.httpmethodattribute.order?view=aspnetcore-5.0) property to some value (by default -1 should do the trick):

```
[HttpPost("Order", Order = -1)]
```

`HttpMethodAttribute.Order` Property:

> Gets the route order. The order determines the order of route execution. Routes with a lower order value are tried first. When a route doesn't specify a value, it gets the value of the Order or a default value of 0 if the `RouteAttribute` doesn't define a value on the controller.

Or set the property with the same name of `RouteAttribute` on the controler:

```
[Route("Cart", Order = -1)]
```

Comment: It did the trick. Thank you, you saved my life =) It was really simple though

Comment: @AntonGelenava was glad to help!